# Perl print "$("

Tags: perl

I'm just starting to learn Perl, and I (accidentally) came across this `print` behavior I can't explain. If I do:

```
print "$(";
```

the result I get is:

```
1000 4 20 24 25 27 29 30 44 46 117 1000 1001
```

Comment: [`$(`](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#$\()

Comment: [https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$(](https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$%28)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is known as a [Special Variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#SPECIAL-VARIABLES).  From `perldoc perlvar`:

```
$REAL_GROUP_ID
$GID
$(
```

> The real gid of this process. If you are on a machine that supports
> membership in multiple groups simultaneously, gives a space separated
> list of groups you are in. The first number is the one returned by
> getgid(), and the subsequent ones by getgroups(), one of which may be
> the same as the first number.

etc.